# How to safely redirect between pages

Tags: security, redirect, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a Flask Web-App with lots of different subpages that redirect to each other. Up until now I always pass a HTTP Parameter next.

Lets say the User comes from

`/old/url`

and visits

`/new/url?next=/old/url`

then I just parse the Http request and check if there is a next param:

`return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('.index'))`

The problem that I found is that I also have an API endpoint for deletion. 
So there could be a malicious crafted link like:

`/new/url?next=/item/delete/<item_id>`

So when a user is redirected that item is deleted. And because the user is most likely authenticated the server will treat the request as a valid request.

Are there any best practices for stuff like that (either my api endpoint or the redirections)?

Greetings

Comment: You can fix this by only accepting explicit DELETE requests for /item/delete/<item_id>. This way you avoid accidentally deleting an item with a POST or GET request.

Comment: I thought about that and that fixes the issue. But then it could be possible to mess around with different endpoints. If I have for example: user/unfollow/<username> that endpoint has to accept GET or at least a POST request. I wonder if my idea to provide the next param is any good. But I see it used in a lot of flask apps.

Comment: If you use proper authorization only an authorized user can access the endpoint so there is no room to mess around.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I am thinking about the edge case, that a user clicks on a malicouis link that was provided by a third party, e.g. received via email. In that case the user is logged in and  authorized. Its an edgecase but it is possible.

Comment: Yes that's right, that's the reason why one should never click a link in an email ;) But that can potentially happen to you with every Website or API.

Comment: Okay. So I will leave it this way. Thank you :)